# sonata SonataClassificationBundle - fields types

Tags: sonata-admin

```
   protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form)
    { 
     ->add('tags', ModelType::class, [
                'class' => SonataClassificationTag::class,
                'property' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
                'compound' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'btn_add' => true,
                'btn_list' => true,
            ])
```

this render

[image]

why i cannot add tag ?
i cannot find example ussage for classification-bundle

https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataClassificationBundle/en/4.x/reference/introduction/

is install only manual ..
whith fields i should use ?